# Replace files recursively

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, unix, filesystems

I have a deeply nested directory called `MyProject` which contains dozens of git repositories. Each of those repositories contains, somewhere, a directory called `utils` which contains a file called `analytics.js`.

I want to replace all occurrences of `analytics.js` with `~/Desktop/new-analytics.js`.

How can I do this in unix?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you find the files to be replaced:

```
find MyProject -type f -path "*/utils/analytics.js"
```

To overwrite them all with a single file:

```
find MyProject -type f -path "*/utils/analytics.js" -exec cp -i ~/Desktop/new-analytics.js {} \;
```

Notes:

- `-type f` is in case one or more `analytics.js` turns out not to be a regular file (e.g. a directory).
- `cp -i` just in case. Omit `-i` after you verify that my answer is sane.
- I assumed that each `analytics.js` (to be replaced) is directly under some `utils/`. If you're interested also in files in subdirectories of `utils/` then try this:

  ```
  find MyProject -type f \
     '(' -path "*/utils/analytics.js" -o -path "*/utils/*/analytics.js" ')' \
     -exec cp -i ~/Desktop/new-analytics.js {} \;
  ```
- In context of `-path` `*` can match a string containing slash(es).